# AuthenticationHandler<TOptions> on a .net5.0 library

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-5, asp.net5

This is probably an issue between the chair and the keyboard, but... I'm failing to implement a custom authentication handler on a class library with .net5.0.

From the docs, [AuthenticationHandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.authenticationhandler-1?view=aspnetcore-5.0) is now part of `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref` which is an *internal* reference. So, my guess would be that when targeting .net5.0, this would be handled.

Before .net5.0 this was part of [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication/) and compliant with `netstandard2.0`. I did try referencing this library, but that (obviously) collides when hosted by the aspnet application.

You might ask so... Yes, I did try to add a reference to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref` though that fails with the message *"incompatible with 'all' frameworks in project"*.

So... I guess my question is... how on earth can I implement a custom `AuthenticationHandler<TOptions>` with `.net5.0` on a class library project?

I also saw that I do have access to the `IAuthenticationHandler` interface, though that will require a "full" implementation.

Any comment towards a solution is welcome...

Cheers!

Comment: You can use `AuthenticationHandler` abstract class as the starting point, no need to implement the whole interface. https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/3535cfb61dd955a7fa6c31bdf72a3eba5353f1ce/src/Security/Authentication/Core/src/AuthenticationHandler.cs#L18

Comment: The issue is that `AuthenticationHandler` isn't available, using this target and project type.

Comment: What I have done for now is to implement `IAuthenticationHandler` interface, since the implementation is rather simple. Since this is not an answer but a workaround, I'll keep the issue open for a better answer.

Comment: The answer and the project I've linked to [works on .NET 5](https://github.com/abdusco/Lib.AspNetCore.Auth.Intranet/blob/1cd021fb0a25b7ea8de445f8d9d891eda4fe471a/src/Lib.AspNetCore.Auth.Intranet/Lib.AspNetCore.Auth.Intranet.csproj#L4). You can check out the one for [JwtAuth](https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer/JwtBearerHandler.cs,24) or the one for [Twitter](https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Twitter/TwitterHandler.cs,df3bee234ea31052) (it uses `RemoteAuthenticationHandler` which in turn uses `AuthenticationHandler`).

Comment: Also, it's _not_ a workaround. It's the way Microsoft itself does it. See the links above.

Answer (score 3):

You can subclass `AuthenticationHandler` abstract class and use it as the starting point.

```cs
public class IntranetHandler : AuthenticationHandler<IntranetOptions>
{
    // ...
    protected override async Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

You also need to add a reference to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` to access this type.

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <!-- ... -->
    <ItemGroup>
        <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

I have [a mini library that I've written for intranet authentication](https://github.com/abdusco/Lib.AspNetCore.Auth.Intranet) that you can use for reference.

Comment: Thanks for replying. `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` is outdated and intended for target netcore2.

Comment: That's certainly not true. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/target-aspnetcore?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: Of course it is. From your link "Referencing ASP.NET Core in this manner is only supported for projects targeting .NET Core 3.x.". However, there's also a link to a GitHub issue addressing the same issue https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/22048

Comment: @adbusco this is actually accurate. I misread your answer and you are referencing `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` via a `FrameworkReference` and this does work. Thanks!